# Given an arbitrary language L is there an algorithm that terminates and decides whether the language is regular or not?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, regular-language

I have an arbitrary language $L$ (with finite amount of symbols $k$), assume the language can be represented in finite space as an input, you can also assume that we can check for $w\in\Sigma^*$ whether $w\in L$ (in finite time)

I have the following algorithm

```
n=1;
while(true){
  calculate_enumeration_of_all_n_DFA(n) enum; 
  forall(a in enum){
    if (L(a)=L) 
    return a
  }; 
n=n+1
};
```

The algorithm may not terminate but if it does we have proved that $L$ is regular

Is there an algorithm that decided whether $L$ is regular and terminates?

And if not, is it because we have not found one yet - or is it because there cannot exist one?

Comment: Just one question: how do you check whether $L(a)=L$?

Comment: Depending on how L is presented, it might be undecidable even to check whether L is _empty_ or not, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Please proof-read your question, and adjust the formatting.  Please don't put your entire algorithm on one very long line.  How is the language $L$ presented as input?  There are uncountably many languages, so it is not trivial how to represent a language in finite space.  Please [edit] your post based on the feedback you have received.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin we know that L(a) is regular, so we could use methods from comformance testing, for example the $W$ method from Chow see (Chapter 4) https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b137241

Comment: Your edit doesn't address the feedback/comments.  Such a function cannot be represented in a finite input.  The input to any algorithm must be finite.  Also, please don't use "Edit:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.